# Best practice for configuring local python package imports for github repo?

Tags: python, git, python-import

I'm newish to imports so it's possible my approach is patchy but i'm really struggling to piece together how this is supposed to be done.

So I have a github repo I am working on that currently looks something like this:

```
Github-repo-name
   /src
      /repo-name
         __init__.py
         /packages
            __init__.py
            mypackage1/
               __init__.py
               p1_module1.py
            mypackage2/
               __init__.py
               p2_module1.py
         main.py
      /scripts
         do_something.py
      /datasets
```

I'm trying to import mypackage1 into do_something.py in order to generate some data to put in datasets/ but was having lots of trouble when I ran the do_something.py script in the *src* directory.

I had this line in do_something.py:

```
import repo-name.packages.mypackage1
```

and was hitting: *ModuleNotFoundError: No module named repo-name*

I tried relative imports to no more success

```
from ..repo-name.packages import mypackage1
```

ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

I couldn't make head or tail of this issue so I instead tried adding my packages to the path in do_something.py

```
file_path = pathlib.Path(__file__)
path = file_path.resolve().parents[2]
sys.path.append(str(path))

import repo-name.packages.mypackage1
```

Success!

Except now i'm wondering if this really what I *should* be doing and if this isn't a bit hacky. The idea of needing to add the path at runtime seems a bit messy so i'd rather have it all the time. I've read I can use PYTHONPATH for this purpose which would be great if it were just me using this repo, but I intend for this to be shared and reproduceable. I thought about maybe writing a shell script to set the PYTHONPATH but i'm not sure that's much better.

So my question is what is the right/better/a good way of doing what i'm trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

Oliver. 
I don't know what is the best way, but I'm trying to show you how our team works.

When developing, 
i) register `PYTHONPATH` in `~/.bashrc` 
ii) `sys.path.append(path/to/root/repo)` on the top of the code

Our team usually does it as an initial way.

To distinguish whether they receive the authority of repo or not, you can check the below.

```
# Suppose you created a setup.py(to make `.whl` file) on `repo-name`.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    from repo-name.packages.mypackage1 import *
else:
    from ..repo-name.packages.mypackage1 import *
```